# organize a deck of cards in accending order

Tags: java

Hi I wrote some code to print out a deck of cards

this is how is coming out: 2C  2D  2H  2S  3C  3D  3H  3S  4C...

this is how I want it : 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C...

here is part of my code :

```
public DeckOfCards()
{
  for (PlayingCard.CardRank rank : PlayingCard.CardRank.values())   
    for (PlayingCard.CardSuit suit : PlayingCard.CardSuit.values())           
    {
       System.out.printf(" %c%c ", rank.getSymbol(),suit.getSymbol());
    }
}
```

I was planning on using a for loop, but I am not sure where to start any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are very close: switch around the two loops to get the effect that you are looking for.

```
for (PlayingCard.CardSuit suit : PlayingCard.CardSuit.values())
    for (PlayingCard.CardRank rank : PlayingCard.CardRank.values())
```

Everything else looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Swap around the order of your nested for loops. That is, change it to:

```
for (PlayingCard.CardSuit suit : PlayingCard.CardSuit.values())
      for (PlayingCard.CardRank rank : PlayingCard.CardRank.values())
```

Remember that the inner loop gets run to completion once for every time through the outer loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like it might be as simple as:

```
for (PlayingCard.CardSuit suit : PlayingCard.CardSuit.values())
{  
    for (PlayingCard.CardRank rank : PlayingCard.CardRank.values())   

    {
       System.out.printf(" %c%c ", rank.getSymbol(),suit.getSymbol());
    }
}
```

.. swapping out the two nested for loops.